# Issue with Jquery working in older version, but not newer

Tags: jquery

I have this Jquery and I've manage to get it to work (Im not very good at jQuery). But I can't get it to work in v1.11.0. This will work in v1.8.3. When I switch up the version the clickme button seems to be swallowed up. 
Here is Fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/meD7b/782/

Here is the code for those of you that will be able to see it without having to look at the fiddle.
JQUERY

```
$("#dropbuttons").css({"top": "0px"});
$("#drop_button").toggle(function () { 
    $("#dropbuttons").animate({"top": "+115px"}, "slow"); 
},
function () { 
    $("#dropbuttons").animate({"top": "0px"}, "slow"); 
});
```

I've tried searching all over to find out why this is the case but I haven't been able to figure it out. 
Can someone here help me get this to work in the 1.11.0 version please?

Comment: toggle does not work in v1.11.0

Comment: `.toggle()` was deprecated as an event in 1.8 and removed in 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: On the other hand, it's not deprecated as an animation, so use a click handler and do `$("#dropbuttons").animate({"top": "toggle"}, "slow");`  instead -> **http://jsfiddle.net/meD7b/793/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Toggle Event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)**

> This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed
>   in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named
>   .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the
>   animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments
>   passed.

Currently **[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** is an animation method provided by jQuery.

---

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meD7b/796/)**

```
$("#div2").css({"top": "0px"});
$("#clickme").click(function () {
    if ($('#div2').css('top') !== '115px') {
        $("#div2").animate({"top": "+115px"}, "slow");
    } else {
        $("#div2").animate({"top": "0px"}, "slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked great and explains why when I checked the code in jslint, and jshint that it didn't find any errors. It also explains when I looked to see if the toggle command was still there that I found it.. I just didn't look to see that it changed its function. Thank you so much all for the help.

Comment: Yes It is confusing sometimes in such cases. Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

So as `.toggle()` event is deprecated in 1.8 and you want to use 1.11+ you can do something similar to [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/shzP3/)

using `.on` instead to handle the click event.

```
$("#clickme").on('click', function(event) {
    var toggle = $("#div2"),
        animation = { top : "+115px" };

    if (toggle.css('top') !== "0px")
        animation.top = "0px";

    toggle.animate(animation, "slow");
});
```

This example doesn't have any checks to see if the animation is in progress, you may want to add that in before using it.

You can also use the `.toggle` animation if you wished rather than conditional css checking.

Comment: This was a good answer as well and worked, however I liked the above answer more. Thank you david.